# Water line won't stay connected to aftermarket freezer port

Tags: water, appliances, ice-maker

We have a Whirlpool model ET1MHKXMT01.  Apparently an aftermarket top freezer icemaker was installed in unit and had been working fine for years.

At some point moving the fridge appears to have caused the a line that runs into the back of the ice maker on the freezer to disconnect, possibly break.  We tried to reconnect it but the line keeps popping out now whenever the ice maker pulls water.  A repair guy told me there is some clip missing he can't find anywhere.

I called a parts for whirlpool but hey said the original does not show these parts.

I wondering if that port is part of the fridge or the icemaker?  Note a metal ring inside the water line.
wondering if these are factory or aftermarket and what fix i can make?  do most after market ice makers come with this hardware?

[image]

[image]

Below are images of after market ice makers.  Are we missing any of these parts. Is this a repair we can do from the back?

My water line end looks like this (NOT ACTUAL):

[image]

updated port pic. waiting on better line pic

[image]

Comment: pictures updated. it looks like this. seems i just need a clamp. wonder where i can get that?

Comment: Maybe. Photo's still fuzzy. I can't tell what would seal the connection. Can you? Doesn't look like a clamp alone will help given those slits in the fitting.

Comment: Your 1st two photos do NOT show the same fitting as the next two photos.  Which photos are the one in the back of the refrig?  Also the connecters required for the top are different from one is required on the bottom.

Comment: yeah..  you are right. hold for better pics

Comment: I am very confused on what connections you actually have. Can you delete any non relevant  and out of focus photos.

Comment: sorry for bad pic. from memory it looks like the stock pic, but waiting on updated pic.  i sent an updated pic i had of the port.  wondering what clip i need or if maybe i need to do repairs inside the freezer after pushing the line through?

Comment: I found the install video for my ice maker and there is no clip. still waiting on pic. https://www.appliancepartspros.com/whirlpool-icemaker-wpw10715708-ap6023924.html

Comment: Some soft tube connectors have a metal insert to allow compression on the soft tubing and it will still seal. Yours looks different but that’s what I thought you were looking for.

Comment: When you insert the tubing into the refrig fitting, does it fit snugly, or very loose???

Comment: It fits snuggly but not super tight, but i've been unable to get into the property this week.  i suspect our only issue is that there is nothing keeping the hose on the fridge, just need some 3m two sided tape to reattach it.  Side question , if i remove the icemaker will there  be whole in the freezer from a part that was removed during installation?

Answer (score 1):

It is very common in refrigerators to use push-to-connect fittings for joining polypropylene water lines. If that is the kind of connector in use previously, yours appears to be broken (some examples [here](https://cdn.mscdirect.com/global/images/ProductImages/7552280-23.jpg) and [here](https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/5229a6b7-ba6f-49c3-9b13-59aaf81b2bf1/svn/white-john-guest-polypropylene-fittings-nc2099-64_1000.jpg)) and the metal ring is likely part of the broken connector.

If the fridge was never sold with an ice maker, then it would have not had any need for a water intake port. Therefore, that part must have been part of the aftermarket kit used. What you may want to consider instead of looking at the model number of the fridge is looking for a model number/manufacturer for the ***ice maker***. If you can find one (you might need to remove a panel or take the ice maker loose to find it) you may be able to use that to track down a replacement part instead.

If you can't find a replacement port, consider just drilling a slightly larger hole in the port and replacing the existing polypropylene line all the way up to the ice maker with a slightly longer water line and use a connector on the outside of the fridge such as [this](https://www.mscdirect.com/product/details/06584254), [this](https://www.espwaterproducts.com/john-guest-straight-inline-ball-valve-1-4-x-1-4-quick-connect-fittings-ppsv040808w/), or [this](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSZFF6FFYPayIkqLjpfgrs_NCl7WXkmdPDHwLkBD1oOB9-pnEka&usqp=CAU). You can usually get replacement polypropylene hoses at home depot or lowes by the foot. You may also be able to find the push-to-connect fittings too - just make sure they are the right size and you don't break the one going into your ice maker too!